# Launching html response in browser (or playing flash)

Tags: paw-app

I have a POST request that returns an HTML page with embedded flash

Trying to run it from Paw directly (i.e. choosing 'Web') shows 'Blocked Plug-in'. Is there a way to either unblock this or to open the response in a web browser?

Thanks!

Comment: You can export the response from `File > Export Response > Response Body` and open this in a browser. However, many browsers may block content such as Flash loaded from a static file on disk.

Comment: OK, that works, but it's a bit long winded having to export every time then loading the file into a browser. Is there a way to get this done in one step that you know of?

Comment: At the moment this is the only way, but we'll be adding action scripts in the future, since we are sandboxed you will only be able to save to a limited set of directories without a prompt, need to look into if we can trigger your default browser to open the file safely.

Comment: OK, great. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to right-click on the URL in the response view and hit "Open Link in Web Browser"

[image: Open HTML response in web browser from Paw HTTP Client]

Comment: This doesnt work with a POST request/response as far as I can tell

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to "open" a POST request in a web browser (that would be a major security flaw for browsers).